# Can all textures embedded at once?

Tags: texturing, workflow, image

Is there any function which allows to embed all used textures at once in the .blend file?

I have multiple .blend files with dozens of textures and would prefer not to do this one by one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you want is located in *Info > File > External Data*:

[image]